# Create new dimension using values from another dimension in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, grouping

I currently have a SQL table that looks something like this:

```
   RuleName      | RuleGroup
---------------------------
Backdated task   | DRFHA  
Incorrect Num    | FRCLSR
Incomplete close | CFPBDO
Appeal close     | CFPBDO
Needs letter     | CFPBCRE
Plan ND          | DO
B7IND            | CORE
```

I am currently writing a stored procedure in SSMS that pulls these dimensions from the existing table. However, I also want the procedure to create a new dimension that will create a "SuperGroup" dimension for each rule based on the text in it's RuleGroup (and an other column for the rest). For example:

```
   RuleName      | RuleGroup | SuperGroup
--------------------------------------------
Backdated task   | DRFHA     | Other
Incorrect Num    | FRCLSR    | Fore
Incomplete close | CFPBDO    | DefaultOp
Appeal close     | CFPBDO    | DefaultOp
Needs letter     | CFPBCRE   | Core
Plan ND          | DO        | DefaultOp
B7IND            | CORE      | Core
```

I have currently tried used the "GROUP BY" function, as well as using SELECT with several "LIKE" statements. However, the issue is that this needs to be scaleable - although I only have 21 groups right now, I want to automatically sort if new groups are added.

Here is the SSMS procedure as well:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Rules].[PullRulesSpecifics]
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
    ru.RuleName
    ru.RuleGroup
FROM RuleData.groupings ru
WHERE 1=1
AND   ru.ActiveRule = 1
AND ru.RuleOpen >= '2015-01-01'
```

Comment: ssms is a management interface, which happens to be able to run sql. there is no such thing as an "ssms procedure". there's stored procedures in mssql, which you can MANAGE with ssms.

Comment: How are you, "SELECT with several "LIKE" statements"?  This is important because you want your solution to be scalable and not hard-coded to your current 21 groups.

Comment: Exactly - I was unable to find anyway to make this scaleable using that method. I'm trying to find a way to make the procedure automatically sort RuleGroup (including any new ones) each time it is run.

Comment: @RishiMehta Okay, let me ask this differently, how do you know to which SuperGroup your Group belongs?

Comment: Ah, I misread. Each SuperGroup will be based on keywords. For example, anything containing "CORE" will go into a CORE SuperGroup, anything containing "CFPB" will go into CFPB, etc. Anything not in the keywords for any group will go into an "other" SuperGroup.

However: if something contains "CFPB" and "CORE", I want it to go into "CORE"

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: (the Normalized option)
Assuming that your database is well normalized, you should have a Foreign-Key constraint on your RuleGroup column that prevents users from entering whatever they like in there.  This way, only valid RuleGroup values can be entered into the table.  If this is that case (which I suspect it is not) then you can add a column to the Foreign-key table (the one that hold the list of valid RuleGroup values) that indicates to which SuperGroup the RuleGroup belongs.  (The SuperGroup column would ideally have a FK constraint on it as well that references another table that contains all of the valid SuperGroup values.)  If you use this approach, then there is no coding involved whenever a new SuperGroup is added.  It maintains itself.

Option 2: (Not a best practice, try option #1 if you can)
Create a new SuperGroups table with 2 columns: `SuperGroup` and `MatchingCriteria`.  Then you can join on the new SuperGroups table.  (Note that this assumes that each `MatchingCriteria` is going to be mutually exclusive.  If not, then you could match more than 1 SuperGroup and get results you might not have intended.  Either that or you will have to find some other way to limit the results to a single SuperGroup.)  The Query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    ru.RuleName,
    ru.RuleGroup,
    sg.SuperGroup
FROM RuleData.groupings ru
JOIN RuleData.SuperGroups sg ON ru.RuleGroup LIKE sg.MatchingCriteria
WHERE ru.ActiveRule = 1
AND ru.RuleOpen >= '2015-01-01'
```

I removed the WHERE 1=1 code.  It was unnecessary and was probably just there to help you debug your problem.

Comment: My issue is this: for something like "CFPB CORE", I want to filter it into the CFPB group but not the CORE group.

Comment: SOLVED thanks! I ended up creating a table that just places anything else in other for now.

Comment: @RishiMehta I'm glad to help.  If this helped solve your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.